# Cross correlation function in more than one dimension

Tags: cross-correlation, spatio-temporal

The cross correlation function is

$CCF(\tau) = \int f(t)g(t+\tau)dt$

**My question**: are there any extensions to higher dimensional spaces? For instance, assuming space dimension $x$ is orthogonal to temporal dimension $t$,  something like:

$CCF(s,\tau)=\int \int f(x,t)g(x+s,t+\tau) dt dx$

A discretized version would suffice. I am more concerned with conceptual aspect of this. The closest I've seen is the Normalized [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation) but there is no concept of lag here. Basically I need a cross correlation function that is 2-D or N-D.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. I did not think of using the Variogram for this. However, I see that the sample Variogram can be sensitive to binning which is an issue in my current application. Are there any other approaches that support higher dimensions but more similar to the ones frequent in the signal processing community? (e.g. $ccf(\tau)$ and wavelet correlation analysis)

Comment: The sample variogram can be--and often is--analyzed without any binning at all.  The graphical analog is called a "variogram cloud" and the analytical techniques include weighted least squares and maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: Thanks, whuber. I ended up using the variogram and wls to get an analytical function. Do you see any issue in going form the variogram to the covariance and normalizing it to get linear correlations? In my short researcher career I have noticed that dependency is better communicated in this fashion (with correlations).

Comment: For most applications there is a mathematical equivalence between the covariance and the variogram.  The variogram is needed for handling fields that have no limiting variance (which can usually be avoided in practice).